# How can I run a command on all clients at a time from the server that all are connected to NIS & NFS server?

Tags: networking, opensuse, nfs, nis

Here is an overview of my NIS and NFS configured network.

1 NIS server, 1 NFS server, 50 NIS & NFS clients.

OpenSUSE 13.2

I need to run a command on all clients from a server machine.

Command: an installation command on **local** system.

Example: `zypper install gedit`

The `gedit` package should be installed on local system.

Suggestions?

P.S.: I'm the root user.

Comment: Something automated like ansible should work for you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pdsh` allows you to issue a command to run in parallel on multiple remote machines, worth a look.

RPM : http://software.opensuse.org/package/pdsh

Details : https://code.google.com/p/pdsh/wiki/UsingPDSH